# Dynamic range in solver VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Want to use dynamic range in Solver VBA to loop it through many rows.

Some thing like (presently it is not working, needs to correct it)

```
SolverOk SetCell:=Cells(i, 6), MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Range(cells(i, 14):cells(i, 18)).Value , _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
```

```
SolverReset
SolverOk SetCell:="$F$3", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$N$3:$R$3", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$N$3:$R$3", Relation:=4, FormulaText:="integer"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$F$3", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
SolverOk SetCell:="$F$3", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$N$3:$R$3", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverOk SetCell:="$F$3", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$N$3:$R$3", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve (True)
```

Please help.

Comment: More details, what's not working? what errors. Sample data and expected results are always helpful.

Comment: @5202456 ... 24601 surely

Comment: In given code , want to make $F$3 & $N$3:$R$3 ranges dynamic so that I can loop through various inputs. For example I can change $F3 as ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test").Cells(i, 6).Value , not able to figure out for  $N$3:$R$3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by,

```
For Single cell -> Cells(i, 6)
```

AND

```
For Range -> Range(Cells(i, 14), Cells(i, 18))
```

It may be easy for most of others but still I am posting this answer for beginners like me.